# Tool tip on mouseover a disabled checkbox in a gridview in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, tooltip, mouseover

I have a gridview with checkboxes to select the rows. I am binding the gridview from sql database table. I have a column called reserved. If the reserve is yes then I am disabling the checkbox in gridview and viceversa. Below is the code I am using:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GdvTestData" runat="server" 
                class="table table-striped table-responsive table-hover" 
                onrowdatabound="gv_RowDataBound" 
                PageSize="100" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GdvTestData_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" 
                        Enabled='<%# Eval("ReserveStatus").ToString().Equals("N") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BorderStyle="Solid" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

What I also need is to display a tool tip on mouseover of the disabled row/checkbox. I need to display a text with user info which is saved in a session variable as tool tip. I looked into many articles but dint find the suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following attribute to the checkbox

```
ToolTip='<%# Session["Result"].ToString() %>'
```

Result being the session variable you are looking to access. Don't forget to change it

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.Check below

In the code behind

```
 protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
                if (ReserveStatus == "Y")
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    e.Row.ToolTip = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["TicketId"].ToString();
                }


            }
        }
```

And in .aspx file

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" ToolTip='This row is reserved'
                        Enabled='<%# Eval("ReserveStatus").ToString().Equals("N") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```